# What is the equivalent of an IISReset if I want to use Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: iis, iisreset

It would appear that there is more involved than just iterating the ApplicationPools and calling Recycle() on them.  How do I most closely mimic an IISReset programatically (from .Net) without resorting to shell invocation?

And I suppose most importantly: Are there things that IISReset does that can't be accomplished via the tools available in Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController (got the idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831477/start-and-stop-iis-on-remote-machine-through-c-sharp-code)), by starting or stopping the following services:

-Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)
-World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)

Here's some code that'll do the job:

```
//stop iis (like running "IISReset /Stop")
ResetService("WAS", false);
ResetService("W3SVC", false);

//start iis (like running "IISReset /Start")
ResetService("WAS", true);
ResetService("W3SVC", true);

private static void ResetService(string name, bool start)
{
    using (var service = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(name))
    {
        if (start && service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            service.Start();
        }
        else if (!start && service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            service.Stop();
        }
    }
 }
```

As for other IISReset commands, you could code in a timeout easily enough. And to reboot the computer, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215139/reboot-machine-from-a-c-wpf-app). Let me know if you need any more details.

But if that's not enough of a party for ye, you can always execute power shell scripts in c#, using [this technique](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) (pretty baller, if you just need to get 'er done).