# How to force reboot Windows 7 from inside a C# Windows Service

Tags: windows, service

I need to (force) reboot Windows from inside a Windows Service written in C#.
The ordinary way of doing it, from a desktop application, shutdown.exe, will probably not work at all? I assume I cannot run an EXE file from inside a service..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reboot machine from a C#/WPF app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215139/reboot-machine-from-a-c-wpf-app)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Win32 API [`InitiateSystemShutdown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873.aspx) and/or [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874.aspx) function.

Also refer to this MSDN article: [Shutting Down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it, but it does not work inside a Windows Service, it seems..